# Is Hematogen non-kosher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, food

[Hematogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hematogen) is non-kosher ("blood"), right?

Hematogen is done (indirectly) from blood of an animal. Does it imply that it is non-kosher?

Answer (score 1):

[Hematogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hematogen)

> Hematogen (Russian: Гематоген, Gematogen; Latin: Haematogenum) is a
>   nutrition bar, which is notable in that one of its main ingredients is
>   black food albumin taken from processed (defibrinated) cow's blood.<sup>[1]</sup>
>   Other ingredients may vary, but usually they're sugar, milk, vanillin.

Defibrinated blood is whole blood from which the clotting protein (fibrin) has been removed.

If this was all that had been done, it would mean that it is definitely **not** kosher. As we see in Leviticus [Tzav 7:26](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9908#v=26&showrashi=true)

> 26 And you shall not eat any blood in any of your dwelling places,
>   whether from birds or from animals.

Even if the blood had been processed to make it a *neutral* chemical or the product did not have blood in it, then it would have to be treated as not kosher unless it was certified by a reputable kashrus agency.

Comment: @mevaqesh I used the word imply bacause that was the question. The implication is because it is from the blood of an animal which is explicitly forbidden.

Comment: How do you know that blood is forbidden? More significantly, how do you know that it is still considered blood? Most significantly, how do you know that bittul would not apply?

Comment: @mevaquesh because the pasuk explicitly forbids it and the discussion on gelatine which is not explicitly forbidden shows this

Comment: Remember to always cite your sources and arguments in posts themselves.